# where to put stuffs(icons, color, stencils in .rar file) downloaded from official android developers site in ecplise

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm pretty new to android. I stuck at a point where I need to add a downloaded .rar file for icons, stencils and color swatches into Eclipse (the RAR file has been downloaded from official android developer site.here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html)).

Is there any way to directly copy and paste in ADT bundle root folder and use it or we have to do it by copying and pasting into the drawable folder each of the required itens?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the "res" folder of your android project.
Just drag and drop (or copy past) an image in the "drawable" folder.

**You have to do that for each item.**

If you have different size for an image you can put the ressources of your image in those folders: "drawable-hdpi", "drawable-ldpi" and "drawable-mdpi".

Each folder represent a screen size for your device.
Note that each ressource must have the same name (Eclipse should manage it).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for all the images by copying the images <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> then in Eclipse select drawable(hpdi,...) folder, right click -> Paste

Or

1 - Extract the RAR file

2 - Store the contents of the extracted folder in ZIP format

3 - Right click (the project) -> import -> General -> Archive File

4 - Move the imported content to the required res folder (drawable ,drawable-hpdi,...)